# Rails 4 multi-page app on PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymotion

I've built a plain (no frontend js frameworks) Rails app that uses materialize. It works quite well in a mobile browser, but I want to use PhoneGap (or something else if necessary) to wrap it into a mobile app. There don't seem to be any current guides on how to do that. Could anyone please point me in the direction on how to do that?

EDIT: Should I use rubymotion instead? How long will that learn to use and implement?

Answer (score 1):

If you go with Rubymotion, the only time you will spend on is getting Rubymotion set up and running.

Then you can pretty much grab a "hello world" tutorial (or any motion sample app) and add a few lines that point to your site. For iOS it looks like this:

```
    request = NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(rails_app_url)
    view.loadRequest(request)
```